# static 2d array initialisation

Tags: c++, arrays, static

### How to initialize static 2d array

I am trying to initialize static 2d array by statment 'static int b[n][m]={}' , it is showing error, while on giving const parameters, it's working 'static int b[2][10]={}'

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void a(int c, int n, int m){
static int b[n][m]={};
// static int b[2][10]={}; , here it is working fine
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
        b[i][j] = i+j;
    cout<<b[i][j]<<" ";
    }
}

}

int main(){

int c;
cin>>c;
a(c,2,10);
    cout<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable-length arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c)

Comment: You already give the answer. Do you want to know why it is not working as you wish, or what is your question?

Comment: The `static` is a red herring; there are no variable-length arrays in C++.

Comment: I wanna initialize variable length static 2d array..... how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

you already initialized your array by 0.

if you whant initialize to something else try this

static int ar[2][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};